# Can we create custom heading into csv file when we converting the json file into python

Tags: php, python

My current program is converted pdf to CSV file by using python. and the CSV file is generated according to JSON file using php code.
I want to create another csv file in which I am able to change the heading of csv file.

Currently I am using these code to get the json file and downloaded into csv file`

```
<?php

@set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ob_start();

require_once( "../include/core.php" );
require_once( "../include/api_check.php" );

$apiCheck = APICheck();
if ( is_string( $apiCheck ) )
    die( $apiCheck );

if ( $apiCheck == false )
    if ( !User_IsLoggedIn() )
        exit;

$outputType = 'single';
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['output'] ) )
    $outputType = $_REQUEST['output'];

$filename = '';
$json = '';

if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) && User_IsDev() )
{
    $filename = 'rawdata.csv';
    $json = $_POST['data'];
}
else
{
    $id = db::$link->real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['id'] );

    $userid = "UserID = '" . User_GetID() . "' AND ";
    if ( $apiCheck )
        $userid = "";

    $query = "SELECT Filename, JSON, DownloadStats FROM uploads WHERE " . $userid . "ID = '" . $id . "'";
    $result = db::query( $query );
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    $filename = $row[0];
    $json = $row[1];

    // update download stats
    $download_stats = $row[2];

    $download_stats = json_decode( $download_stats, true );
    $download_stats['lastOutputDownload'] = time();
    $download_stats['numOutputDownloads']++;

    $download_stats = json_encode( $download_stats );
    $download_stats = db::$link->real_escape_string( $download_stats );
    $query = "UPDATE uploads SET DownloadStats = '" . $download_stats . "' WHERE UserID = '" . User_GetID() . "' AND ID = '" . $id . "'";
    db::query( $query );
}

// parse and serve output
if ( $outputType == 'json' )
{

    $json = json_decode( $json, true );
    $json = json_encode( $json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

    if ( $apiCheck )
        header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
    else
    {
        $filename = pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '_output.json"'  );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
        header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $json ) );
    }

    echo $json;
    exit;
}

function format_data( $s = '' )
{
    $s = trim( $s );
    $s = str_replace( "\n", ' ', $s );
    $s = str_replace( ',', ' ', $s );
    return $s;
}

$json = json_decode( $json, true );

// metadata legend
$csv .= "KEY,VALUE\r\n";

// metadata csv
foreach ( $json['metaData'] as $key => $data )
{
    $csv .= format_data( $key ) . ",";

    $text = format_data( $data );
    if ( empty( $text ) )
        $text = 'not in invoice';

    $csv .= $text . "\r\n";
}

// splitter
$csv .= "\r\n================\r\n\r\n";

// entry legend, default values
$default_values = array( 'name', 'value' );
foreach ( $default_values as $key )
    $csv .= strtoupper( format_data( $key ) ) . ",";

// entry legend, keys in json
$keyCache = array();
foreach ( $json['entries'] as $entry )

//  print_r($json['entries']);

    foreach ( $entry as $key => $data )
        if ( !in_array( $key, $keyCache ) )
            $keyCache[] = $key;

foreach ( $keyCache as $key )
    if ( !in_array( $key, $default_values ) )
        $csv .= strtoupper( format_data( $key ) ) . ",";

$csv = substr( $csv, 0, -1 );
$csv .= "\r\n";

// convert entries
foreach ( $json['entries'] as $entry )
{
//  print_r($json['entries']);
    foreach ( $default_values as $dk )
        $csv .= format_data( $entry[$dk] ) . ",";

    foreach ( $keyCache as $key )
    {
//      print_r($key);
        $value = $entry[$key];
        if ( !in_array( $key, $default_values ) )
            $csv .= format_data( $value ) . ",";
    }

    $csv = substr( $csv, 0, -1 );
    $csv .= "\r\n";
}

// free some ram
unset( $json );

// re parse if single part
if ( $outputType == 'single' )
{
    $split = explode( '================', $csv );
    $csv = '';

    $metadata = str_getcsv( trim( $split[0] ), "\n" );
    foreach( $metadata as &$row ) $row = str_getcsv( $row );
    array_shift( $metadata );

    $entries = str_getcsv( trim( $split[1] ), "\n" );
    foreach( $entries as &$row ) $row = str_getcsv( $row );

    // free some ram
    unset( $split );

    // generate metadata legend
    $legend_metadata = '';
    foreach ( $metadata as $mrow )
        $legend_metadata .= $mrow[0] . ',';
    $legend_metadata = substr( $legend_metadata, 0, -1 );

    // generate metadata values
    $metadata_values = '';
    foreach ( $metadata as $mrow )
        $metadata_values .= $mrow[1] . ',';
    $metadata_values = substr( $metadata_values, 0, -1 );

    // generate entry legend
    $legend_entries = '';
    foreach ( $entries[0] as $key )
        $legend_entries .= $key . ',';
    $legend_entries = substr( $legend_entries, 0, -1 );
    array_shift( $entries );

    // generate csv
    $csv .= $legend_entries;
    $csv .= ',';
    $csv .= $legend_metadata;
    $csv .= "\r\n";

    foreach ( $entries as $erow )
    {
        $row_csv = '';
        foreach ( $erow as $val )
            $row_csv .= $val . ',';

        $row_csv .= $metadata_values;       
        $csv .= $row_csv;
        $csv .= "\r\n";
    }
}

// output file
$filename = pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

if ( $apiCheck )
{
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
}
else
{
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '_output.csv"'  );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $csv ) );
}

echo $csv;

?>
```

`

Comment: any updates please?

Comment: Yes, we can.. there you go.. now you can mark the question as answered...

Comment: Here's an awesome page with a lot of good info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read the link and try to post a question that actually follows those guidelines... You need to be _specific_ and you need to show us the relevant code, where you have an issue and what you've tried. You're current question is "Can we..", which I actually answered. Other than that, it's impossible to understand what and where your issue is...

Comment: okay, thanks for the updates. actually I want to implement custom heading into csv file and I have only json file. so can you please guide some code or link which is helpful

Comment: No... I won't guide you until you show us what you tried... This isn't a free coding service....

Comment: The above code I am using it

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do. But first dont put your php code and asks for python. Secondly, dont copy the whole code of your application, paste the relevant one. Show us what you did and where you get stuck or facing issues.
For doing Json to CSV with specific header below is the brief example :

```
json_data="""[{'Fname':'Ashu', 'Lname':'Dagar', 'Phone':'1234567890'}]"""

import csv
import json
data = json.loads(json_data)
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

#writing specific header to csv
f.writerow(['Fname','Lname'])

#write data to csv
for value in data:
    f.writerow([value["Fname"], value["Lname"]])

you will get output as :
Fname,Lname
Ashu,Dagar
```

if you have lost of keys in your json then you can define your own dict which acts as a header in csv and get the values from the json for the same keys which you defined in the dict, which gives you the data.